# Delphi: sliding (animated) panel

Tags: delphi, animation, panel, sliding

Is there a sliding (animated) panel component for Delphi?

For instance it can be found in [Raize Components](http://www.raize.com/devtools/RzComps/images/RCDemo_vsGradient_SystemWinClassic.png) (a left panel with a "Hot Spot" or hide/show button).

I need not a resizeable panel but a panel that can slide horizontally and smoothly from the left to the right + that has a hide/show button (it's not a big deal if without that button).

Thanks!

Comment: This article might be of use: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphi-tips-2011/qt/hide-slide-fade-away-controls-delphi-form.htm

Comment: See FoldingPanel v1.3 here: http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=2386
I used it for years. Has a nice chevron bitmap too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try [NLDSideBar](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDSideBar), a container component written by myself that is collapsable and aligned along the left or right side of its parent.

Interface:

```
property Align: TSideBarAlign default alLeft;
property AutoHide: Boolean default False;
property Hint: String;
property MinWidth: Integer default DefWidth;
property OnAutoHideChanged: TNotifyEvent;
property OnHide: TNotifyEvent;
property PinButtonDownHint: String;
property PinButtonUpHint: String;
property PinButtonVisible: Boolean default True;
property Resizable: Boolean default True;
property SideButtonWidth: Integer default DefSideButtonWidth;
property Caption;
property Color default clBtnFace;
property Font;
property ParentColor default False;
property ParentFont;
property ParentShowHint;
property PopupMenu;
property TabOrder;
property TabStop;
```

[image: NLDSideBar]

Or maybe [this older version](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDSnapPanel) which is animated. Free to use, free to modify.

<sup>Sorry for being self-promotive, but I think it's an answer to the question.</sup>

Comment: You don't have to apologize for self-promotion, it is perfectly acceptable as long as you disclose your involvement.

Comment: I will always upvote self-promotion of free open source stuff!

Comment: I will always upvote self-promotion if they answer the question perfectly.

Comment: and you seems never to update it beyond Delphi 7 :-)
I tried it in xe2, put two right-side panels - and behaviour I sadly less than intuitive... Guess you always only had one panel at side :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks! It's a bug. Add `BringToFront` at the end of each block in `UpdatePlacement`.

Comment: Can several buttons for same-side collapsed panels be put into one row, like tabs ?

Answer (score 11):

We ended up building our own control.  We could not find anything that worked quite how we wanted.  It ended up not being that hard.  I'm sure there are situations we are not handling correctly, but so for this is working good for us.

The code below is using cxGroupBox because we needed that look to match the rest of our application.  That can be switched out for a normal GroupBox.

We are using this in two places.  In one case we have a number of these panels inside a standard Delphi Flow Panel (I'm not sure what version that was added).  When our DynPanel collapses everything automatically moves up and fills the space.

In the other case we have a window that is split between a main section and a toolbox.  The two are separated by a standard splitter.  The main window is set to align to client.  When our panel collapses or expands. the splitter automatically moves and expands the main section.

We never did quite get the "container" control stuff to work so items you add to the panel can be moved outside the bounds you would normally expect in a group box.  But that does not cause us any major problems so we just left it.  This also does not account for DPI changes in relation to the button size.  The caption will get bigger but the button will not.

```
unit DynPanel;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls, cxGroupBox;

const
  DEFAULTBUTTONWIDTH = 16;
  DEFAULTWIDTH  = 161;
  DEFAULTHEIGHT = 81;
  cButtonPadding = 8;
  cCollapsePadding = 3;
  cCaptionPadding = '       ';
  cCollapsedSize = DEFAULTBUTTONWIDTH + cCollapsePadding;
  cAutoCollapseSize = DEFAULTBUTTONWIDTH + cButtonPadding;

type
  TCollapseDirection = (cdUp, cdRight, cdLeft);

  TMinDemension = cAutoCollapseSize..High(Integer);

  TDynPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    FGroupBox: TcxGroupBox;
    FButtonPanel: TPanel;
    FButtonImage: TImage;

    FExpand: Boolean;
    FOldHeight: Integer;
    FOldWidth: Integer;
    FCollapseDirection: TCollapseDirection;
    FOrigGroupBoxCaption: String;
    FAutoCollapseHeight: TMinDemension;
    FAutoCollapseWidth: TMinDemension;

    FButtonPadding: integer;
    FCollapsePadding: integer;
    FCollapsedSize: integer;

    procedure SetExpand(Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetGroupBoxCaption(Value: string);
    procedure ButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_SHOWINGCHANGED;
    procedure EnableControls(Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetCollapseDirection(Value: TCollapseDirection);
    procedure ConfigurePanel;
    procedure SetMinHeight(Value: TMinDemension);
    procedure SetMinWidth(Value: TMinDemension);
    procedure UpdateImage();

  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
    procedure ChangeScale(M, D: Integer); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    property OldHeight: Integer read FOldHeight write FOldHeight;
    property OldWidth: Integer read FOldWidth write FOldWidth;
    property GroupBox: TcxGroupBox read FGroupBox;
  published
    property Caption: string read FOrigGroupBoxCaption write SetGroupBoxCaption;
    property Expand: Boolean read FExpand write SetExpand;
    property BevelOuter default bvNone;
    property CollapseDirection: TCollapseDirection read FCollapseDirection write SetCollapseDirection default cdUp;
    property AutoCollapseHeight: TMinDemension read FAutoCollapseHeight write SetMinHeight default cAutoCollapseSize;
    property AutoCollapseWidth: TMinDemension read FAutoCollapseWidth write SetMinWidth default cAutoCollapseSize;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

{$R 'ButtonImages\ButtonImages.res' 'ButtonImages\ButtonImages.rc'}

uses cxEdit;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('AgWare', [TDynPanel]);
end;


{ TDynPanel }

{
  TDynPanel.Create
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
constructor TDynPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Self.ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];

  Self.Width := DEFAULTWIDTH;
  Self.Height := DEFAULTHEIGHT;
  BevelOuter := bvNone;

  FExpand := True;
  FOldHeight := Self.Height;
  FOldWidth := Self.Width;
  FOrigGroupBoxCaption := 'AgDynPanel';
  FCollapseDirection := cdUp;
  FAutoCollapseHeight := cAutoCollapseSize;
  FAutoCollapseWidth := cAutoCollapseSize;

  FGroupBox := TcxGroupBox.Create(Self);
  FGroupBox.Parent := Self;
  FGroupBox.Align := alClient;
  FGroupBox.Alignment := alTopLeft;

  FButtonPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FButtonPanel.Parent := Self;
  FButtonPanel.Top := 0;
  FButtonPanel.Width := DEFAULTBUTTONWIDTH;
  FButtonPanel.Height := DEFAULTBUTTONWIDTH;
  FButtonPanel.Left := Width - DEFAULTBUTTONWIDTH - FButtonPadding;
  FButtonPanel.OnMouseDown := ButtonMouseDown;

  FButtonImage := TImage.Create(Self);
  FButtonImage.Parent := FButtonPanel;
  FButtonImage.Align := alClient;
  FButtonImage.Stretch := false;
  FButtonImage.Center := true;
  FButtonImage.OnMouseDown := ButtonMouseDown;

  UpdateImage;

  // The click should also work for the entire top of the group box.
  FGroupBox.OnMouseDown := ButtonMouseDown;

  FGroupBox.Caption := FOrigGroupBoxCaption;
  FGroupBox.Style.Font.Style := FGroupBox.Style.Font.Style + [fsBold];

  FButtonPadding := cButtonPadding;
  FCollapsePadding := cCollapsePadding;
  FCollapsedSize := cCollapsedSize;

end;

{
  TDynPanel.SetGroupBoxCaption
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.SetGroupBoxCaption(Value: String);
begin
  FOrigGroupBoxCaption := Value;
  ConfigurePanel;
end;

{
  TDynPanel.SetMinHeight
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.SetMinHeight(Value: TMinDemension);
begin
  if Value = FAutoCollapseHeight then
    Exit; // >>----->

  FAutoCollapseHeight := Value;

  if Showing then
    Resize;
end;

{
  TDynPanel.SetMinWidth
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.SetMinWidth(Value: TMinDemension);
begin
  if Value = FAutoCollapseWidth then
    Exit; // >>----->

  FAutoCollapseWidth := Value;

  if Showing then
    Resize;
end;

{
  TDynPanel.ButtonMouseDown
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.ButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button  mbLeft then
    Exit; // >>----->

  if ((FExpand = True) and (Y  FCollapsePadding)) or
     ((FExpand = False) and (FCollapseDirection = cdLeft) and (X >----->

  FExpand := Value;

  //ConfigurePanel;

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Set the group box size
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //
  // I chose to do the resizing of the control here rather than in
  // ConfigurePanel because if you do it there the SetBounds will call ReSize
  // which will call ConfigurePanel again so that you would need to keep track
  // of a boolean variable to determine if you are making recursive calls into
  // ConfigurePanel. That is one reason. Another is that when the dfm values
  // are streamed in and the properties get set you will resize the control
  // before the actual Height and Width properties are set. This will cause
  // bogus default values to be stored for FOldHeight and FOldWidth and when
  // the control is displayed the dimensions will be wrong. If you size the
  // control here then, on creation, Resize will not get called and the
  // FOldHeight and FOldWidth values will not get saved off until
  // CMShowingChanged will explicitly call ReSize after the dimensions are
  // properly set. If you move this code into ConfigurePanel then when the
  // caption is streamed in and set from the dfm then ConfigurePanel would get
  // called, we would SetBounds there and then Resize would fire storing off the
  // default invalid values for the FOld variables as mentioned above.
  // Hope this makes sense. Leave the SetBounds calls here and make your life
  // easier. :)
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Changing to Expanded
  if FExpand = True then
  begin
    // Up
    if FCollapseDirection = cdUp then
      SetBounds(Left, Top, Width, FOldHeight)
    // Right
    else if FCollapseDirection = cdRight then
      SetBounds((Left + Width) - FOldWidth, Top, FOldWidth, Height)
    // Left
    else if FCollapseDirection = cdLeft then
      SetBounds(Left, Top, FOldWidth, Height);
  end
  // Changing to Collapsed
  else
  begin
    // Up
    if FCollapseDirection = cdUp then
    begin
      // Reset the AutoCollapseHeight just to make sure we don't try to
      // recollapse on resize.
      if FAutoCollapseHeight  FGroupBox) and
       (Self.Controls[i]  FButtonPanel) then
    begin
      Self.Controls[i].Enabled := Value;
      Self.Controls[i].Visible := Value;
    end;
  end;
end;

{
  TDynPanel.CMShowingChanged
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if Showing then
    Resize;
end;

{
  TDynPanel.Resize
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.Resize;
begin

  if FExpand = True then
  begin
    if (FCollapseDirection = cdUp) and (Height  FAutoCollapseHeight then
      begin
        FOldHeight := Height;
        Expand := True;
      end
      else
        Height := FCollapsedSize;
    end
    else if (FCollapseDirection = cdLeft) or (FCollapseDirection = cdRight) then
    begin
      if (Width > FAutoCollapseWidth) then
      begin
        FOldWidth := Width;
        Expand := True;
      end
      else
        Width := FCollapsedSize;
    end;
  end;

  ConfigurePanel;

end;


{
  TDynPanel.ChangeScale
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.ChangeScale(M, D: Integer);
begin

  FAutoCollapseHeight := MulDiv(FAutoCollapseHeight, M, D);
  FAutoCollapseWidth := MulDiv(FAutoCollapseWidth, M, D);

  FButtonPadding := MulDiv(FButtonPadding, M, D);
  FCollapsePadding := MulDiv(FCollapsePadding, M, D);
  FCollapsedSize := MulDiv(FCollapsedSize, M, D);


  FOldHeight := MulDiv(FOldHeight, M, D);
  FOldWidth := MulDiv(FOldWidth, M, D);

  // inherited will cause resize to be called.  I need to update
  // my internal values before that happens, otherwise I will resize based
  // on the old values.
  inherited;

end;

{
  TDynPanel.SetCollapseDirection
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.SetCollapseDirection(Value: TCollapseDirection);
begin
  if Value = FCollapseDirection then
    Exit; // >>----->

  FCollapseDirection := Value;

  ConfigurePanel;
end;

{
  TDynPanel.ConfigurePanel
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.ConfigurePanel;
begin
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Set the group box style, caption alignment, caption, button position, and
  // button image
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Changing to Expanded
  if FExpand = True then
  begin
    FGroupBox.Style.Color := clWhite;
    // Up
    if FCollapseDirection = cdUp then
    begin
      FGroupBox.Alignment := alTopLeft;
      FGroupBox.Caption := FOrigGroupBoxCaption;
      FButtonPanel.Top := 0;
      FButtonPanel.Left := Width - FButtonPanel.Width - FButtonPadding;
    end
    // Right
    else if FCollapseDirection = cdRight then
    begin
      FGroupBox.Alignment := alTopLeft;
      FGroupBox.Caption := '       ' + FOrigGroupBoxCaption;
      FButtonPanel.Top := 0;
      FButtonPanel.Left := FButtonPadding;
    end
    // Left
    else if FCollapseDirection = cdLeft then
    begin
      FGroupBox.Alignment := alTopLeft;
      FGroupBox.Caption := FOrigGroupBoxCaption;
      FButtonPanel.Top := 0;
      FButtonPanel.Left := Width - FButtonPanel.Width - FButtonPadding;
    end;
  end
  // Changing to Collapsed
  else
  begin
    FGroupBox.Style.Color := clGradientActiveCaption;
    // Up
    if FCollapseDirection = cdUp then
    begin
      FGroupBox.Alignment := alTopLeft;
      FGroupBox.Caption := FOrigGroupBoxCaption;
      FButtonPanel.Top := 0;
      FButtonPanel.Left := Width - FButtonPanel.Width - FButtonPadding;
    end
    // Right
    else if FCollapseDirection = cdRight then
    begin
      FGroupBox.Alignment := alRightTop;
      FGroupBox.Caption := '       ' + FOrigGroupBoxCaption;
      FButtonPanel.Top := FButtonPadding;
      FButtonPanel.Left := FCollapsePadding;
    end
    // Left
    else if FCollapseDirection = cdLeft then
    begin
      FGroupBox.Alignment := alLeftTop;
      FGroupBox.Caption := FOrigGroupBoxCaption + '       ';
      FButtonPanel.Top := FButtonPadding;
      FButtonPanel.Left := 0;
    end;
  end;

  UpdateImage;
  // Now draw the button and invalidate Self
  Self.Invalidate;
end;

{
  TDynPanel.UpdateImage
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TDynPanel.UpdateImage();
begin
  case FCollapseDirection of
    cdUp:
      begin
        if FExpand = true then
          FButtonImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'ButtonImageUp')
        else
          FButtonImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'ButtonImageDown');
      end;
    cdLeft:
      begin
        if FExpand = true then
          FButtonImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'ButtonImageLeft')
        else
          FButtonImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'ButtonImageRight');
      end;
    cdRight:
      begin
        if FExpand = true then
          FButtonImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'ButtonImageRight')
        else
          FButtonImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'ButtonImageLeft');
      end;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Close to the Left
[image: Left Open] [image: Left Closed]

Close to the Top
[image: Top Open]

---

[image: Top Closed]

Comment: Looks nice. However you did not specified the license :-)

Does it account for an option to have two or three sidebars side by side ?

Comment: @Arioch'The I thought the code was covered under the default StackOverflow CC license.  If you need something different from me you can use it under "unlicense" http://unlicense.org.  I have not tried multiple items side to side.  We use it vertically with a flow panel.  Our main edit screen as 10+ of these stacked on a Flow Panel which is then inside a Scrollbox.

Comment: CC also has many "editions". "I thought the code was covered under the default StackOverflow CC license" - well, you might THINK so, but any person who would attempt to use it would face the "better safe than sorry" problem. I am okay with any non-viral FLOSS license, though due to lack of time I would perhaps stick with TCategoryPnel, despite it does not meat all my wishes....

Answer (score 5):

The new Delphi version will include such kind of sliding panels ( trough the integration of FireMonkey, formely vgScene/dxScene ). You'll just have to click on height or position props and an option will allow to create a animation for this, with various option ( interpolation kind, duration etc).

[image]

Comment: This would be a good answer, if OP was using Firemonkey. You can't use FMX controls in a VCL app very easily :-)

Comment: I agree with JD. Mentioning Firemonkey here does not help.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 2009, there is a [TCategoryPanelGroup](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ExtCtrls_TCategoryPanelGroup.html) where you add TCategoryPanel.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! "I need not a resizeable panel but a panel that can slide horizontally"

Comment: This one is not resizeable... but, it's only vertical ;o(

Answer (score 3):

**FoldingPanel**
See FoldingPanel v1.3 here: http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=2386
I used it for years.
It comes with nice chevron bitmap too.
Small issue: it does not support composite controls (like TLabeledEdit).
Advantage: The component comes as a single PAS file (easy to install into the Palette). They say that it is for Delphi 5 but I have it installed in XE7 and works without problems (which indicates quality).
Freeware

**TSplitView**
If you have a newer version of Delphi (like Tokyo) you can use TSplitView.
Note: The Align property it missing. And at the beginning it might seems that it can only be aligned to Left. But it is not true. Instead of an Align property it has a Placement property (with two values: svpRight / svpLeft).
Note: It has some small glitches related to control size/placement.
Note: It is not (NOT EVEN BY FAR) as complete as FoldingPanel. You still have to write some cod eto implement some kind of chevron to collapse/expend the panel.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hUG8o7PpCU
Freeware (if you have Delphi Tokyo).

**TCategoryPanelGroup**
Also take a look at TCategoryPanelGroup. It might or might not work, depending on what you need it for.
Freeware (if you have Delphi XE7)

Comment: Good option you have shared with us.